# Fewer threads updating value than expected with omp_set_num_threads()

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, hpc

Why does this program print the result as 64 and not 5000? If the count variable is being updated in the critical section, I would expect that only one thread should have access to it at any given point in time. Thus, each thread would be able to increment the count, and produce the result 5000, so why do I get 64 instead in answer?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    omp_set_num_threads(5000);
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << "count = " << count << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Michael Dussere points out, you're getting 64 as an answer because your implementation is only launching 64 threads.  It may be using an internal default value to limit the max number of threads (try varying the environment variable  `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT`, or calling `omp_get_thread_limit()` to see if that is the case.)

The reason for such a limit is that creating threads requires resources - each thread has to have its own stack space, process table entries on linux, etc. These aren't lightweight stateless Erlang threads that are scheduled in user space.  On my 8-core system using gcc or icpc, setting the thread number to anything 1024 or above simply fails due to lack of resources, although setting system parameters can shift that limitation around.

Between the resources required by the threads and the fact that most single-image system have significantly fewer than 5000 cores, it's not clear what you'd be able to accomplish with 5000 threads on most systems.

Comment: Jonathan Dursi, how then do I add two arrays of say 5000 elements each? How can 64 threads carry out SIMD addition of 5000 elements?

Comment: @user3670482 , just use `omp parallel for`, and don't worry about the number of threads; the decomposition will be done for you, and each thread will handle multiple items.  That is the usual approach in OpenMP - this isn't CUDA, or even SIMD (which can also be invoked through OpenMP now in 4.0, but is something separate) - it's a coarser grained parallelism where it is usual, and even necessary for performance, for a thread to handle multiple items.

Answer (score 2):

The value you can set with omp_set_num_threads is not unlimitted. 
It depends of the OpemMP implementation you use, the number of cores of you computer and so on.

You get 64 because there should be 64 threads in the current thread team. You can check with omp_get_num_threads.